# Flask App in Docker Container Fails in Connecting to PostgreSQL : Error This site can’t be reachedThe connection was reset

Tags: postgresql, docker, flask, dockerfile, port

I am trying to deploy a Flask application within a Docker container which should connect to a PostgreSQL server on the host machine. The application runs with Gunicorn and is set up to listen on port 8000. However, I am unable to access the app through the browser; I keep getting a "connection was reset" error.

I've followed the recommended settings, but when I navigate to 127.0.0.1:8000 or localhost:8000, I encounter the error as shown in the attached screenshot.

I have tried mapping different ports it doesn't work, it works locally though when

```
DockerFile

# Use an official Python runtime as a parent image
FROM python:3.8 

# Set the working directory in the container
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the current directory contents into the container at /app
COPY . /app

# Install any needed packages specified in requirements.txt
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

# Make port 8000 available to the world outside this container
EXPOSE 8000

# Define environment variables
ENV FLASK_APP=postgres_attempt.py
ENV FLASK_RUN_HOST=0.0.0.0

# Use Gunicorn to run the application
CMD ["gunicorn", "--config", "gunicorn_config.py", "postgres_attempt:app"]
```

```
Gunicorn_config.py

bind = "0.0.0.0:8000"
workers = 1
threads = 1
timeout = 600
```

```
postgres_attempt.py
(Python Code)

from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, url_for
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, SubmitField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired

app = Flask(__name__)
# Use host.docker.internal instead of localhost
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'postgresql://postgres:zxcvbnma@host.docker.internal/postgres_attempt'
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'DX2651ANK_4152'

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class Example(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(100))
    message = db.Column(db.String(1000))

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'<Example {self.name}>'

class ExampleForm(FlaskForm):
    name = StringField('Name', validators=[DataRequired()])
    message = StringField('Message', validators=[DataRequired()])
    submit = SubmitField('Submit')

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    form = ExampleForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        example = Example(name=form.name.data, message=form.message.data)
        db.session.add(example)
        db.session.commit()
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    examples = Example.query.all()
    return render_template('index.html', form=form, examples=examples)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    
    with app.app_context():
        print("Creating tables...")
        db.create_all()
        print("Tables created.")
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0',debug=True)
```

```
entrypoint.sh

#!/bin/sh

# Entry point script for Flask application

echo "Starting Flask app with Gunicorn..."

# Start Gunicorn with the specified configuration
exec gunicorn --config gunicorn_config.py postgres_attempt:app
```

After doing some more digging I found out that I had issues with the docker daemon running. Is it a system issue?

Comment: How are you running the container?

Comment: By doing a simple docker run -p 8000:8000 followed by my image name on terminal